# Can you make a foreign key from two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I have three tables (mail,country and client). Table COUNTRY is parent table for table MAIL, so primary key od table MAIL is postcode from MAIL and countrycode from COUNTRY. I need to add a foreign key in table CLIENT that is made of postcode and countrycode but I want postcode in that foreign key to come from COUNTRY not MAIL. I only know how to make foreign key in CLIENT from MAIL:

```
CREATE TABLE COUNTRY (countrycode char(3), 
CONSTRAINT pk_country PRIMARY KEY(countrycode))

CREATE TABLE MAIL (postcode numeric(5), countrycode char(3),  
FOREIGN KEY(countrycode) REFERENCES country(countrycode), 
CONSTRAINT pk_mail PRIMARY KEY(postcode,countrycode))

CREATE TABLE CLIENT (OIB numeric(11), postcode numeric(5), countrycode char(3),
FOREIGN KEY(postcode,countrycode) REFERENCES mail(postcode,countrycode), 
CONSTRAINT pk_client PRIMARY KEY(OIB))
```

BUT I don't want that. I want my countrycode in table CLIENT to come from COUNTRY not from MAIL.
I've tryed:

```
FOREIGN KEY(postcode,countrycode) REFERENCES mail(postcode) AND country(countrycode)
```

but it doesn't work.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: _Is there a way to do that?_ No there is not. Each referential integrity constraint can only reference one parent relation. You will need to revise your requirement or your model.

Comment: A foreign key needs to point to a primary key. A primary key logically cannot span multiple tables. So no, a foreign key can only point to one table.

Comment: A word of advise about the design. Do not make `COUNTRY` its own table. Countries are well known values. Use the ISO country code as values. The names of country codes can be retrieved from libraries in the front end. Along with that there is not a good reason to have a `MAIL` table, scrap that as well. If you want to see if a postal code combination is valid there are APIs you can call or libraries you can import.

Comment: What happens when the countrycode/postcode in client, doesnt match up with the countrycode/postcode in mail? The whole point of keys is to ensure data integrity. Your data model is wrong!

Comment: A fk must reference _one complete_ key. I.e. `FOREIGN KEY(postcode,countrycode) REFERENCES mail`.

Comment: IMO you only need one table: `CLIENTS` with columns `OIB numeric(11), postcode char(5), countrycode char(3)`. No foreign keys at all. Postal code should be a string/chars/vachar, it is not numeric (when have you ever needed to increment a postal code or add one to another?)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use compound primary keys.  Don't replicate data across multiple tables.  So, look up the country based on the post code.  I would suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE COUNTRIES (
    countryid int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    countrycode char(3) unique
);

CREATE TABLE PostCodes (
    postcodeid int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    countryid int references countries(countryid),
    postcode nvarchar(25),
    unique (countryid, postcode)
);

CREATE TABLE CLIENTS (
    clientId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    OIB numeric(11) unique,
    postcodeid int references postcodes(postcodeid)
);
```

Note some things:

- You can look up the country via the postal code.
- Postal codes are not always numeric.
- Countries change over time (e.g. East Timor, South Sudan).
- Postal codes can change (e.g. 10021 on the Upper East Side of Manhattan split into 10065 and 10075, once upon a time).

Comment: Hmm, but I don't want table Postcode. By saying table mail I was refferring to Postoffice. I need a table Postoffice, but Postoffice has to have primary key made of postcode and countrycode. Because Postoffice is settled in one place and that place has its poscode and couldn't exist without country. Postoffice is child table of table country. We learned that when you have relationship parent and child table, child's table primary key is made of its primary key and parent's primary key. Or you can say weak and strong entities

Comment: Ah. You should read up on "surrogate keys", they make life simpler (and, in some cases, more complex). If you are not using them, what you'd need in table CLIENT is something like columns CountryCode and PostOfficeCountryCode--that is, presumably one for the client, and a separate one for the client's post office. (Having a surrogate key on PostOffice, and using that key in Client, would clear out a lot of confusion here.)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have a *single* foreign key reference *multiple* tables, but you don't need to: You can have multiple foreign keys per table, so you can just reference both.

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT (
   OIB numeric(11), 
   postcode numeric(5), 
   countrycode char(3),
   FOREIGN KEY(postcode,countrycode) REFERENCES mail(postcode,countrycode), 
   FOREIGN KEY(countrycode) REFERENCES country(countrycode), 
   CONSTRAINT pk_client PRIMARY KEY(OIB)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other posts have presented a number of arguments regarding your existing table structures, some (imho) more valid than others. My reply is based solely on your existing structures, and does not attempt to second guess whether they are “right” or “wrong”. (Yes, I have opinions on the topic, but that’s not what you were asking about.)

On the face of it, there’s no need for the FK on column CountryCode in CLIENT to go all the way to COUNTRY to “validate itself”. The FK in MAIL ensures that any CountryCode in MAIL will also be in COUNTRY; so, an FK in CLIENT to MAIL on CountryCode is just as good at validating CountryCode as an FK directly to Country.

The once exception I can see to this is if you need to have a CLIENT with a valid CountryCode, but without a valid MAIL entry. (One thing unclear from your model is whether the columns are NULLable or not.) This might be the case if a CLIENT must have a COUNTRY, but does not have to have a MAIL. To do this, I’d use two FKs: one to MAIL on both columns, and one to COUNTRY on CountryCode… with column PostalCode set to allow NULLs. This way, CountryCode will always be validated against COUNTRY, and CountryCode + PostalCode will always be validated against MAIL--but only when PostalCode is NOT NULL.

Again, whether this is “right” or “wrong” architecture ultimately depends on what problems you are trying to solve—business, performance, storage (volume), and so on.